# adding and removing value to session array

Tags: php, session-variables

I post values to be added to a session array. If a value already exists in the array it should be removed. Both are not resulting in a change of the array.

```
 <?php
session_start();
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/v5/functions/connect_li.php');
//if (!isset($_session['cart'])) $_SESSION["cart"]= 9; 
if (isset($_POST['myresort']) && !empty($_POST['myresort'])) {
    $resorts            = $_POST['myresort'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $resorts;

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION["cart"]);
if (isset($_POST['myresort'])) {
    $key = array_search($_POST['myresort'], $_SESSION['cart']);
    if ($key !== false) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
        $_SESSION["cart"] = array_values($_SESSION["cart"]);
    }
}
echo '</pre>';


if (!empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {
    echo '<a href="/skirerport/">my resorts: ';
    $_SESSION["cart"] = array_unique($_SESSION["cart"]);
    $_SESSION["cart"] = array_filter($_SESSION["cart"], 'strlen');
    $arr_as_string    = implode(',', $_SESSION["cart"]);

    $sql = "SELECT resort FROM sv_resorts WHERE res_id IN ($arr_as_string) ORDER BY resort LIMIT 10";
    //echo $sql;
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($ro = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo $ro['resort'] . " ";
    }

    print_r($_SESSION["cart"]);
    echo "</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this problem? What happens instead?

Comment: What is the contents of `$_POST["myresort"]`? Can you post an example `$_SESSION["cart"]`? Incidentally, your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: as-is the code does not add an unique value and does not remove if the value is already in the array. When I remove the array_search part it does add values again to the array.

Comment: @james  Array
(
    [0] => 3298
    [1] => 1375
    [2] => 2360
    [3] => 105
    [4] => 742
    [5] => 1805
    [6] => 907
    [7] => 1033
    [8] => 1881
    [9] => 43
    [10] => 867
    [11] => 207
    [12] => 215
    [13] => 211
)

Comment: the post value myresort=211

Answer (score 0):

(Ignore this answer, it wont let me delete it via the app)